# Fuses for clock and remote key entry in Subaru Outback 2016

Tags: subaru, fuse, outback

What are the fuse number(s) for the clock and remote key entry in a Subaru Outback 2016 2.5 CVT Premium (USA)?

The Subaru reference material is to vague too answer this question.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It's 26, 10A BACK UP.

Trial and error got the answer.